# switch to sudo user with AND command doesnt work

Tags: sudo, su

I am trying to copy the ssh private key from one user to another user in single shot.

```
sudo su && cp /home/sk/keys/master.pem /home/sg-user/keys/
```

This sequence of commands works well when I run them one by one. But it shows error as,

```
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/home/sg-user/keys/master.pem’: Permission denied
```

When I ran the command above, it switches to root prompt as,

```
root@sk-box:/home/sk#
```

I tried

```
sudo su && cp /home/sk/keys/master.pem /home/sg-user/keys/ && exit
```

to see, if the command exits root terminal after completing the task. But the exit command doesn't have any effect and the prompt doesn't come out of root session....

Note: `sudo su` has been configured to not prompt for password using `/etc/sudoers` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
sudo cp /home/sk/keys/master.pem /home/sg-user/keys/
```

Answer (score 2):

When commands are run they split into a child processes, so when the 'su' command runs it's going to run in a separate process to the cp command and not actually within the root terminal.

The command will work if you run cp with sudo, but it's not going to run inside the root terminal, you'd have to run the commands separately within su to accomplish that.

```
sudo su && sudo cp /home/sk/keys/master.pem /home/sg-user/keys/
```

The 'sudo so &&' is redundant though if you're only trying to accomplish the copy. This should be all that is needed:

```
sudo cp /home/sk/keys/master.pem /home/sg-user/keys/
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> sudo su && cp /home/sk/keys/master.pem /home/sg-user/keys/
> ```

This runs the command `sudo su`. `sudo su` runs an interactive shell as root, it is basically equivalent to `sudo -s` or `sudo bash` (if your shell is bash). Once this command has finished, if it returned a success status, the `cp` command is executed as the original user.

As far as the shell is concerned, `sudo` is an ordinary command, not special shell syntax. So, like with any other command, `&&` is a command separator, and the command on its left is executed first, then the command on its right (if the first command was successful).

> ```
>  sudo su && cp /home/sk/keys/master.pem /home/sg-user/keys/ && exit
> ```

This variant does the same, except that it exits the parent shell once `sudo su` returns and the file has been copied (assuming those operations were successful). The `su` command runs an interactive shell, which runs the commands that you pass it as input, not the commands that the parent shell is going to run later.

If you want to run two commands as root, running the second one only if the first one succeeded, you can invoke `sudo` twice:

```
sudo command1 && sudo command2
```

or you can make `sudo` invoke a shell and use the `&&` operator in that nested shell:

```
sudo sh -c 'command1 && command2'
```

In your case, you're only running a single command, so it's just

```
sudo cp /home/sk/keys/master.pem /home/sg-user/keys/
```

`sudo su` is basically always useless, because both `sudo` and `su` are used to change users. Since `sudo` already runs the specified command as root, `su` is redundant. This just runs a shell as root, which you can do with `sudo su`.